# Is it possible to execute my python script within postman using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, postman

So I'm using postman to get a response body that contains 'salt''.
I then take the salt and manually go to my command line and pass the salt to my python script (sys.argv) and it will then print out 'proof'

Python(2.7):

```
def generate_proof(salt):
    secret_salt =  SECRET + salt
    hexadecimal = secret_salt.decode('hex')
    proof = sha256(hexadecimal).hexdigest()
    return proof


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print generate_proof(sys.argv[1])
```

I wish to automate this process. In Postman there is the section 'Tests' where I have created environment variables like so:

JavaScript:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("response_path", jsonData.responsePath);
```

My end goal is to store the proof returned from the python script as an environment variable in Postman.

Whether or not there is a way to create the same script in javascript only, I don't know. But I would also accept that as an answer.

Comment: Your question is to broad to get specific code answers, but I'd recommend deciding whether you're more comfortable in JS or python, and writing it in a single language with no Postman dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to do this in postman, I don't know much JS but am quite familiar with Python. I can simulate this process in python easily using the requests import. however the purpose of my question was to see if postman had a way to support this...

> run a python script stored locally
> create a custom terminal command using JS
> if I could translate my script from python to Postman JS